# Does the learning rate of the TensorFlow implementation of the Adam optimizer decay?

Tags: tensorflow

The TensorFlow Adam optimizer (tf.keras.optimizers.Adam) implements the Adam optimizer proposed in https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980. In Theorem 4.1 of the original paper, the learning rate α is updated using this equation: α_t = α / sqrt(t).

My question is: is this decay implemented in TensorFlow? Or is the learning rate the same at every iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `learning_rate` in Tensorflow [Adam optimzer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam) does not decay by default and it remains constant throught the training process. You can manually define the learning rate decay using [tf.keras.optimizers.schedules](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules) and assing this to Adam optimzer `learning_rate` to implement.

**For example:**

```
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(initial_learning_rate=1e-2, 
                                                             decay_steps=10000,
                                                             decay_rate=0.9)
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)

model.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```